# Flutter - How to instantiate an object from a Type

Tags: dart, flutter

My aplogoze for the original question. I'm getting confused. This is my actual question.

I have a situation where I need to use some defined classes as an object of type `Type` and instantiate it's object instance. As for now, I'm using self defined static instantiator function to call the constructor and it's working good. So I can just call `Function.apply()` to create an object. Rather than doing that, is there any way I can use the class's `Type` to emulate the class's constructor.

---

What have I tried? They say to use `Mirror`, a solution for Dart's reflection.

`import 'dart:mirrors'` have failed with error

> Target of URI doesn't exists

Or at least if it's not ready provided I don't know where to get the package.

`import 'package:reflectable/mirrors.dart'` with package from **git://github.com/dart-lang/reflectable.git** only defines all `Mirror` implemented classes, but function `reflect` is missing.

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example of what you try to accomplish and at what step you're stuck?

Comment: Mirrors is not available in Flutter.

Comment: i'm sorry sir. original question actually my mistake. i've update it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot create an instance of a class from a `Type` object representing the class, at least not without mirrors (and neither the Flutter nor the web platform supports mirrors).

You cannot tear-off a constructor (yet, I hope we'll add that feature at some point), so the option of creating a static helper function which calls the constructor, and passing the helper function around, is the best current solution.

If you know the number of arguments required by such a function, you don't need to use `Function.apply`, you can just call it directly.

Comment: i'm sorry sir. original question actually my mistake. i've updated it. +1 for your answer

Comment: Makes sense, I've updated the answer (rewritten, more like).

Answer (score 5):

You can tear-off a function if you don't add the parentheses `()`. You don't need `dart:mirror`.

```
void main() {
  // Tear off a global function
  Function myFunction = MyClass.someStaticFunction;

  // Call it statically
  myFunction('arg');

  // Call it dynamically
  Function.apply(myFunction, ['arg']);

  // Tear it off with a precise Function Type
  void Function(String) myFunction2 = MyClass.someStaticFunction;
}

class MyClass {
  static void someStaticFunction(String someArg) {
    print('someStaticFunction $someArg');
  }
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry sir. original question actually my mistake. i've updated it. +1 for your answer

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to user reflection, you can do this.

```
class A {
}
class B {
}

dynamic init(Type cls){
  switch (cls) {
    case A:
      return A();
    case B:
      return B();
  }
}

void main() {
  print(init(A));
  print(init(B));
}
```

As a best practice, to keep organized and avoid using dynamic, you could extend from a common base and call a static constructor.

```
class A extends Base{
}
class B extends Base{
}

abstract class Base{
  static Base init(Type cls){
    switch (cls){
      case A:
        return A();
      case B:
        return B();
  }}
}

void main() {
  print(Base.init(A));
  print(Base.init(B));
}
```

Output:

```
Instance of 'A'
Instance of 'B'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Any risk of circularity in this alternative? When sub-classes are declared in a different file, the two files need to import each other.

Answer (score 0):

For Dart and Flutter projects, Dart supports the keyword `new` for creating instances of classes but in this case we can optionally create the Task object without `new` keyword.

```
class Task {
  String text;
  bool isComplete;

  Task(this.text, [this.isComplete = false]);
}

// Create object and Providing default values for parameters
final task = Task("Do something.", true);
```

You can call this task object as global variable or locally inside the `build` method, e.g;

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final task = Task("Do something.", true);
  ...
}
```

Globally;

```
Class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
   final task = Task("Do something.", true);
   const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

   @override
   State createState() => MyWidgetState();
}

class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 80.0,
      width: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Center(child: Text(widget.text)),
    );
  }
  ...
}
```