# Flutter : How to invoke a class stored in a variable

Tags: flutter, class, dart

How to invoke a class from a variable in flutter?

```
class MyClass {
   ...
   ...
}


var instance = new MyClass();     // normal creation of a class instance


var my_class = MyClass;
var newInstance = new my_class(); // is there any way to invoke this.
```

I know this example doesn't seem to very pretty but in actual implementation it makes much more sense. Thank you

Comment: You can rename `MyClass` to `my_class`. It usually good to keep class name like `MyClass` instead of `my_class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to create an instance of a class from a Type object representing the class.

For more information check out this link:
[Flutter - How to instantiate an object from a Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53801701/flutter-how-to-instantiate-an-object-from-a-type)

Comment: Thank you! I had store an instance to that variable thus solve my issue